# skLabelNodes only working sometimes

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, sklabelnode

So I added two label nodes to my code, and want one to be hidden while the other is shown, and then vice versa once the game begins.

```
class GameScene: SKScene {
    // Declarations
    let startLabel:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
    let scoreLabel:SKLabelNode = SKLabelNode()
    var score = 0

    override func didMoveToView(view: SKView) {
        // Properties
        startLabel.fontSize = 20
        startLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        startLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width*0.5, self.frame.height*0.5)
        startLabel.text = "Touch Paddle To Begin"
        startLabel.hidden = false
        self.addChild(startLabel)

        scoreLabel.fontSize = 20
        scoreLabel.fontColor = UIColor.blackColor()
        scoreLabel.position = CGPointMake(self.frame.width*0.5, self.frame.height*0.75)
        scoreLabel.text = "\(score)"
        scoreLabel.hidden = true
        self.addChild(scoreLabel)
```

Then, when the Paddle is touched, a moveBall() function is initiated and the game begins. This is where I swapped the labels.

```
func moveBall() {

    // Setting Labels
    self.startLabel.hidden = true
    self.scoreLabel.hidden = false

    // Starting game
    self.ball.physicsBody?.dynamic = true
```

However, it only works sometimes. It will work perfectly, and then without changing anything I'll run it again and only one label will show up. Then again and the other label will show up, or the startLabel will show for only a frame then disappear.

Disclaimer: I do not really know how to code, just got an idea for a game and am trying to make it a reality. Apologies if solution is something simple. Also any advice for my code would be appreciated. Thanks!

Comment: Where do you call moveBall()?

Comment: Check the zPosition of your labels and is `ignoreSiblingOrder` set to `false` in your `GameViewController.swift`? If you have a background image, I'm wondering if the labels can sometimes be drawn behind it?

Answer (score 0):

From the information given it should  work correctly. However you should call the moveBall() in the touchesBegan method. Not the update method.

Also if you want it to be called if the user touches the labelNode use the location of touches began. (But I would rather use a sprite instead of a label coz labels are a bit unresponsive coz sometimes finger doesn't touch the label.

So call the moveBall() in the correct method. Give some more info to give a more accurate answer.